# how to validate float against specific format in java?

Tags: java

I want to validate the float type data. I get the rules defined as

```
int precision1 = 3;
int precision2 = 2;
```

The above rule indicates the data format should be of 999.99

The expected validation of 1234.56, should fail from the above rule. 
Also expected validation should fail for float 123.456 from the above rule. 
Expected validation of 123.33 should be successful.

Any thoughts would be appreciated on validation process.

Thanks, 
Kaygee

Comment: I'm not claiming that those rules make sense or reflect the common use of the word "precision", but it looks to me like you want `100 * x` to be an integer in the range [10000, 100000).

Comment: Are you taking in a string? Because if you already have a float you are screwed.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: It is float as input. And not a String.

Comment: I thought of using String.valueOF(myVal). But there are some issues with the rounding, so I am here for help.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
    int precision1 = 3;
    int precision2 = 2;
    float var = 123.12f;
    String varStr = String.valueOf(var);
    if (varStr.length() == (precision1 + precision2 + 1) && varStr.indexOf(".") == precision1) {
        System.out.println(true);
    } else {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. When the value of var is like this 12345.66789f, then varStr would be 12345.688 and I loose the rounding. How do I not loose the rounding.

Comment: As NullUserException said - if you already have a float you're out of luck as internal representation of a float is almost always an approximation of the string input.

Comment: But why do you care about the rounding?  Your data failed its test.  Does this need to be flexible to handle longer "precision2" values?  You won't have a rounding issue with just 2 decimals.

Comment: Yeah, the precision2 should be flexible.Also as said, the float internal representation is approximation of String input. I am going to go with the solution of Greg for now. Thanks all.

Comment: @Keygee, `float` only has 7 digits of accuracy. If you want more accuracy, use `double` which has 16. (In fact, always use double unless you know you have to use float)

Answer (score 1):

The user inputs a String, it is converted somewhere to float, and you try to validate the float. You can't do it like that.

The String representation of a float is a human artifact. Plus, a float tends to only approximate (very closely) the value of a converted String.

If you want to validate the precision the only way to go is to validate the user input String. And store it like a String if you want to keep the precision.

If you *need* a number, for instance to compute with, use a [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). It is designed to keep the precision exactly as given (important for financial calculations). They are *not very nice* to work with, but that's the price you pay if you want exact non-integer values.

**EDIT**

How to use a BigDecimal.

```
 BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("1234.23");
 System.out.println(b1 + " scale was " + b1.scale()); 2
 BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("1234.523536223");
 System.out.println(b2 + " scale was " + b2.scale()); // 9
```

You can obviously test the "precision" by using the scale. If b1.scale() == 2 || b1.scale() == 3 => valid.

Comment: I upvoted for BigDecimal for emphasis on precision.  Even injecting a large (> 7 decimals) float into BigDecimal causes failure.  If you need precision beyond 7 digits, get your data in String or Double format and put into BigDecimal ... you can convert BigDecimal to String and perform pattern matching.

Comment: @Greg there is not really such a thing as a 7 decimals float. See the BigDecimals(double) constructor. But I will add some extra usage comments for BigDecimal.

Comment: I just meant if you send a float with more than 7 decimals you're going to get weird results.  Like putting 123.123456789123456f into the constructor for your float value ... it gets abused by the conversion.